# Sort ObservableCollection in Combobox C# WPf

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to set sorted the ObservableCollection in combobox,

my result without sorted:

[image]

my ViewModel:

```
 private ObservableCollection<IdentificationSystemType> codeTypeEnum;
   public IdentificationSystemType CodeType
     {
         get { return codeType; }
         set { codeType = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("CodeType");
         }
     }
     
       public NewIdentificationSystemViewModel()
    {
        _identificationToAdd = new IdentificationSystem();
        identificationDeviceToAdd = new IdentificationDevice();
       
        _resetIdentificationCmd = new RelayCommand<string>(resetIdentification);
        saveCommand = new RelayCommand<string>(addFunc, canSave);         
         codeTypeEnum = new ObservableCollection<IdentificationSystemType>(Enum.GetValues(typeof(IdentificationSystemType)).Cast<IdentificationSystemType>());
              }
```

I had try with `var ordered = codeTypeEnum.OrderBy(x => x);`   but nothing ..it is the same
my Enum declaration:

```
 public enum IdentificationTypes : int
   {
    TerminalEntryGate = 1,
    TerminalExitGate = 2,
    LoadingAreaEntryGate = 3,
    LoadingAreaExitGate = 4,
    IslandEntryGate = 5,
    IslandExitGate = 6,
    BayEntryGate = 7,
    BayExitGate = 8,
    ScalingAreaEntryGate = 9,
    ScalingAreaExitGate = 10,
    OfficeAreaEntryGate = 11,
    OfficeAreaExitGate = 12,
    TankFarmEntryGate = 13,
    TankFarmExitGate = 14,
    StagingAreaEntryGate = 15,
    StagingAreaExitGate = 16,      
    LoadingBayIdentification = 21,
    LoadingArmIdentification = 22,
    LoadingIslandIdentification = 23,        
    PresetIdentification = 27
  }
```

How can I fix that?
thanks,

Comment: How do you want it sorted? Alphabetically?

Comment: yes by order alphabetic

Comment: You haven't assigned ordered collection >> `var ordered = displaySystemList.OrderBy(x => x);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
codeTypeEnum = new ObservableCollection<IdentificationSystemType>(Enum.GetValues(typeof(IdentificationSystemType))
.Cast<IdentificationSystemType>());
```

to:

```
codeTypeEnum = new ObservableCollection<IdentificationSystemType>(Enum.GetValues(typeof(IdentificationSystemType))
.Cast<IdentificationSystemType>().OrderBy(x => x.ToString()));
```

to force it to be ordered alphabetically.

Answer (score 1):

As your enum is of type int you are ordering your collection by those numbers. If you want to order your collection alphabetically you need to parse the integers to strings first.

You can do this in the key selector function you are giving the `OrderBy` method.

```
var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(IdentificationTypes)).Cast<IdentificationTypes>();
var valueList = new ObservableCollection<IdentificationTypes>(values);
var orderedList = valueList.OrderBy(x => x.ToString());
```

Comment: Since you've mention values shouldn't it be `Enum.GetNames` instead of `Enum.GetValues`?

Comment: @m.rogalski if you only want to work with the string name of the enum. Typicly its better (my opinion) to use the enum object directly and just format it correctly for display ordering etc. Then you don't have to parse it back afterwards.

Comment: You're absolutely right, that makes it a lot clearer and easier to maintain. Haven't thought about parsing problem.